# Testing if a string is a part of a csv list of strings

Tags: strings, csv, xsim

I use the `xsim` package with tags for my exercises. These tags are a CSV lists of strings.

I have a tag called year (`year={2020-2021,2017-2018}`, for instance) which contains school years. I can retrieve this tag with `\PropertyValue` and I would like to test if "2022-2021" is a part of the CSV list.

I suppose I have to begin with "`\if \PropertyValue`" but I don't know how to continue.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,french]{article}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\DeclareExerciseTagging{year}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        width=\textwidth,
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        colbacktitle=black,
        colframe=black,
        colback=white,
        sharp corners,
        beforeafter skip=\baselineskip,
        title={\bfseries\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}\qquad\IfExerciseTagSetTF{difficulty=1}{\normalfont(Niveau 1)}{}},
        after upper=\IfInsideSolutionF{\par\hfill\GetExerciseProperty{year}}    
        ]
        }
    {\end{tcolorbox}}

\xsimsetup{
    exercise/template=custom,
    solution/template=custom,
    solution/print=true
}

\xsimsetup{solution/print=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[year={2020-2021,2017-2018}]
    Exercice niveau 1 
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Solution de l'exercice 1
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

I added the line `after upper=\IfInsideSolutionF{\par\hfill\GetExerciseProperty{year}}` to show the content of the tag

Here is a print screen of the xsim documentation:
[image]

Comment: If you give a minimal example then I can help you. But I have no time to study how to use Xsim, how to create a mentioned csv, how to create a minimal example. This is your task.

Comment: I added a MWE. I hope it helps

Comment: Would you be interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Yes. I compile with LuaLaTeX

Comment: One more question: Which macro contains the string you want to perform a test on? Is it `\GetExerciseProperty{year}`, or is it `\PropertyValue`? Please clarify.

Comment: I am not really sure, I find the xsim documentation not very clear about that. I will put a print screen of the documentation

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the macro `\isintag` with the following syntax:

```
\isintag{tag-type}{value}\iftrue ...yes... \else ...no...\fi
```

For example:

```
\isintag{year}{2020-2021}\iftrue print YES\else print NO\fi
```

The macro can be defined like this:

```
\def\isintag#1#2\iftrue{\expandafter\let\expandafter\param
   \csname ____xsim_attribute_exercise!\csname g_xsim_exercise_id_tl\endcsname ::#1:\endcsname
   \def\test##1,#2,##2\end{\def\test{##2}\unless\ifx\test\empty}%
   \expandafter\paramcorr\param
   \expandafter\test\param#2,\end
}
\def\paramcorr#1#2{\def\param{,#2,}}
```

The code is based on the fact that the `xsim` saves the tag value into the macro with control sequence name:

```
\____xsim_attribute_exercise!\g_xsim_exercise_id_tl ::tag-type:
```

and the body of this macro is in the format:

```
\exp_not:n {data}
```

but I am not sure if a next version of the package will have different internals.

Comment: Thank you @wipet. I will check that